# Disable core PHP extension on Travis CI

Tags: php, php-extension, travis-ci, intl

I'm looking to add an extra Travis-CI job that tests that a library works without the PHP Intl extension being installed (see https://github.com/giggsey/libphonenumber-for-php/pull/46).

The Intl extension is in the PHP build, and there doesn't appear to be a way to turn it off. Is there one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way to do it on Travis currently because many PHP extensions are compiled directly into PHP (intl included). The issue to track/comment on if you need this functionality is here: https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/4701

Note also that as of August 19, 2015, you can run Docker containers on Travis. In order to test with and without the mcrypt extension, I've been using the official PHP docker container, and conditionally installing mcrypt. You can see how this is implemented here: https://github.com/cweagans/mcrypt-polyfill